# Apache2 server inaccessible from outside

Tags: apache, server, ip, apache2, ubuntu-16.04

I have a LAMP(ubuntu-16.04, PHP) setup and while using it I am able to access it from home network, (phones, etc.) but for others it says that the site can't be reached. I go to my page via my IP and have no problem reaching it. Are there any steps that I can do? I have tried running node.js as well and i have the same problem there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is probably a firewall between your home and the Internet. A firewall prevents connections from the Internet. In fact, some one else, in another home, might have a computer with the same IPv4 address as you have. To make your web server public, you need a public IP address (globally allocated uniquely to you) and you need to route that address to your webserver.

Use a webserver proxy service such as [PageKite](https://pagekite.net).

**Alternatively method:**

Your router most likely already has a public IPv4 address. On http://192.168.1.1 or http://192.168.1.254 or a comparable administration page (usually accessible using the user admin with the password admin, or with a user with the same name as your ISP and that same name as password) you can configure your server as a public web server.

Comment: Thanks for helping me